# Jmeter freezes when loading large results file (.csv)

Tags: jmeter

After running a stresstest in Jmeter with 40 threads and over 100k requests I'm left with a relatively large results .csv file (+- 20 MB). I didn't have any listeners running during the test and now I want to open the result in a dummy project.

When I open the results file in any listener Jmeter loads the results pretty quickly. Even when using a response time graph it only takes about 10 seconds to create the graph, but when it's loaded Jmeter freezes and CPU maxes out.

Anybody have any idea why this is happening? I really want to use jmeter to create the result graphs, rather than use excel or an online service but this problem is making it hard because I keep having to restart Jmeter after it freezes.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Here are few options on how you can work it around

1. Try providing JMeter some more Heap. Depending on your os:

   - for Windows - locate `jmeter.bat` file in /bin folder of your JMeter installation
   - for Linux/Unix/MacOSX - `jmeter` file in the same location

   Locate the following line:

   ```
   HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
   ```

   and amend the values to be about 70-80% of your physical RAM.
2. You can use [Graphs Generator Listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/) to create graphs you need **after** test execution by feeding .jtl result file(s) to it.
3. You can use [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper to be able to get graphs both during test execution and online.